# prove there is a sequence of points in a bounded nonempty subset S of R such that limit = sup (S)

Tags: real-analysis

I have a bounded nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, S, such that $sup(S) \notin S$. I am asked to prove that there is an increasing sequence ($s_{n})$ of points in S such that $lim(s_{n})$=$sup(S)$. Is the following satisfactory?

We want to show that there exists $ \{s_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (in S) such that (1) $s_{n}>s_{n-1}$ $\forall n>1$; and (2) given some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ $N$ such that $n>N \implies -\frac{1}{n}<s_{n}-sup(S)<\frac{1}{n}$. The right hand side inequality is trivial, since $sup(S)$ is an upper bound of $\{s_{n}\}$. Thus, we are left to find a sequence of points in S, such that (1) $s_{n}>s_{n-1}$ $\forall n>1$; and (2) $s_{n}>sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}$. That is, for each $n$, we must construct $s_n$ such that $s_{n}> \max\{sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}, s_{n-1}\}$.

Does such an $s_{n}$ exist? Suppose it did not. Then either (1) $\max\{sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}, s_{n-1}\}$= $s_{n-1}$, so that there is no $s_{n}>s_{n-1}$. This means that $s_{n-1}$ is an upper bound of the set. Case A is that $s_{n-1}$ is equal to $sup(S)$. This is a contradiction since we have assumed that $sup(S)$ is not in $S$. Case B is that $s_{n-1}$ is not equal to $sup(S)$. But since $sup(S)$ is an upper bound of the set (and, by assumption, not equal to $sup(S))$, we have, for all $n$, that $s_{n}\leq s_{n-1}<sup(S) $. But then $s_{n-1}$ is both an upper bound of the set, and less than $sup(S)$. This is a contradiction (both in respect of the fact that it implies that $sup(S)$ is not in fact $sup(S)$, and because it implies that $s_{n-1}=sup(S)\in S$).

The second case is (2) that $ max \{s_{n-1}, sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}\}=sup(S)-\frac{1}{n} $ , and so that there is no $s_{n}>sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}$ . But then $sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound of the set, and less than $sup(S)$—a contradiction.

We conclude that there must exist an $s_{n}$ such that $s_{n}>\max\{s_{n-1}, sup(S)-\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Now, choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then $n>N \implies -\epsilon=-\frac{1}{N}<\frac{1}{n}<s_{n}-sup(S)<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}=\epsilon$.

Comment: "Then either (1) $\max\{\sup(S)-\varepsilon ,s_{n-1}\}=s_{n-1}$ so that there is no $s_n>s_{n_1}$"... what does it means exactly ? nothing is defined ! Which $s_n$ do you take ? what is $\varepsilon $ here ?

Comment: Sorry, \epsilon was supposed to be 1\n.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple proof : Set $\ell=\sup(S)$.

- Step 1 : Take $s_1\in S$ s.t. $\ell-1<s_1<\ell$.
- Step 2 : Take $n_2\geq 2$ big enough s.t. $s_1<\ell-\frac{1}{n_2}$. And then, take $s_2\in S$ s.t. $s_1<\ell-\frac{1}{n_2}<s_2<\ell$.

$\vdots$

- Step $k$: Take $n_k\geq k$ big enough and $s_k\in S$ s.t. $s_{k-1}<\ell-\frac{1}{n_k}<s_k<\ell.$

$\vdots$

Then, (according to axiom of choice) the sequence $(s_k)$ is increasing and satisfies $$-\frac{1}{n}<s_n-\sup(S)<\frac{1}{n},$$
for all $n$.